# How to insert dicts into a JSON array file?

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, dictionary

I have written a small Python script which utilizes `speedtest-cli` to get my internet speed every so often. I am planning to create a contraption where my Python script stores the speed data in a JSON array file that already exists on the disk and then have a small webpage setup to view the data.

Anyways, I have configured my script in such a way that it spits out a `dict` at the end of the script that looks like this:

```
{
    "downSpeed": 90.30834444821808,
    "humanTime": "Fri Dec  9 18:02:54 2016",
    "time": 1481328174225.999,
    "upSpeed": 13.698571043448549
}
```

I have a JSON file on the disk that is simply a file with two brackets to represent a JSON array and within that array, I want my script to put the `dicts` in the JSON array, separated by commas to represent the `dicts` as `objects` in JSON. My question is how would I go about entering my data into the JSON file? All the solutions that I have come across have mentioned using the `open` function alongside the `a` option. But, there are a couple of issues with this, first off, the data is being appended to the file and the last bracket of the JSON gets cut off because the data is being appended. Secondly, since I plan to run this script pretty frequently, I am afraid that I will run into an issue where the JSON file will be very long and therefore take a very long time for the script to process. So, what are my options here? Is there another way to insert a `dict` into a JSON array (which I guess loosely translates into a `list` in Python)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the python JSON module? https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html
You can write a python object directly to a JSON file using dumps().
Example from the site:

```
    import json
    print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True,
                      indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

    {
        "4": 5,
        "6": 7

    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's true, but that doesn't solve my issue where if I have an already existing JSON array, how would I insert objects into that?

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no easy way to insert something into the middle of a file. So you would have to parse all the JSON to create a list in memory, append an item, and then dump it again. Or you could mess around with commas and square brackets to manipulate the JSON array manually.

A much better option in this case it to forget the JSON array and just store each JSON object on a single line. This way you can use append mode and also easily iterate through the objects without loading the entire file into memory.

Comment: Would I be able to parse that using JS? Since that won't be syntactically correct JSON ?

Comment: How does javascript come into this? In any case yes it should be easy in javascript to split a large string into separate lines and parse each line separately.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! In my OP, I mentioned that I also wanted a small website to parse the JSON and display the data and I would use JavaScript to parse that data in the JSON

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to append JSON code to an already existing JSON file(.json) then all you need to use is Python's json module. Say you have a file named `test.json` with code,

```
[ "Hello World!", "Testing 1, 2, 3." ]
```

Then you want to append the following Python dictionary to the list.

```
{ "Hello World!": 123, "Test": None }
```

The python code would look like this.

```
import json # import the module

code = json.load(open('test.json','r')) # load the current data
adding_dict = # put the python dictionary here,
              # it can even be a class if it returns a dictionary.
new_dict = code.append(adding_dict) # append the dictionary to the list
# then we dump it to the file.
json.dump(new_dict, open('test.json', 'w'))
```

If you want more on this there is more on Python's documentation site, [here.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: Hmm, weird, after I did that, it just wrote `null`into the JSON file on the first line and nothing else.

This is the code I came up with:


`jsonData = json.dumps(speedData, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))


existingJson = json.load(open('allSpeedData.json', 'r')) #Existing JSON array


insertJson = existingJson.append(jsonData) 
json.dump(insertJson, open('allSpeedData.json', 'w'))`

Comment: Try debugging your code with print. Printing out any variable you create. Please use `;`s in your code for newlines, it makes it hard to read otherwise. The problem is your `insertJson` variable. It needs to just be `existingJson.append(jsonData)`, then when you dump it use `existingJson`. When appending to a list Python doesn't return the full list, it just "appends" or adds onto the original list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import jsonlines

net_speed = {
               "downSpeed": 90.30834444821808,
               "humanTime": "Fri Dec  9 18:02:54 2016",
               "time": 1481328174225.999,
               "upSpeed": 13.698571043448549
            }

# net.jsonl is the name of the file
with jsonlines.open("net.jsonl", "a") as writer:   # for writing
    writer.write(net_speed)

with jsonlines.open('net.jsonl') as reader:      # for reading
    for obj in reader:
        print(obj)
```

visit for more info https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/